# Time between date. (More advanced than just Datediff)

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I have a table that contains Guest_ID and Trip_Date. I have been tasked with trying to find out for each Guest_ID how many times they have had over 365 days between trips. I know that for the time between the dates I can use datediff formula but I am unsure of how to get the dates plugged in properly. I think if I can get help with this part I can do the rest.

For each time this happened I need to report back Guest_ID, Prior_Last_Trip, New_Trip, days between. This data goes back for over a decade so it is possible for a Guest to have multiple periods of over a year between visits.

I was thinking of just loading a table with that data that can be queried later. That way once I figure out how to make this work the first time I can setup a stored procedure or trigger to check for new occurrences of this and populate the table.

I was not sure were to begin on this code. I was thinking recursion might be the answer but I do not know recursion just that it exist.

This table is quite large. Around 1.5 million unique Guest_ID's with over 30 million trips.

I am using SQL Server 2012. If there is anything else I can add to help this let me know. I will edit and update this as I have ideas on how to make this work myself.

---

Edit 1: Sample Data and Desired Results

```
Guest_ID    Trip_Date
1           1/1/2013
1           2/5/2013
1          12/5/2013
1           1/1/2015
1           6/5/2015
1           8/1/2017
1          10/2/2017
1           1/6/2018
1           6/7/2018
1           7/1/2018
1           7/5/2018
2           1/1/2018
2           2/6/2018
2           4/2/2018
2           7/3/2018
3           1/1/2014
3           6/5/2014
3           9/4/2014

Guest_ID    Prior_Last_Trip     New_Trip    DaysBetween
1            12/5/2013          1/1/2015    392
1             6/5/2015          8/1/2017    788
```

So you can see that Guest 1 had 2 different times where they did not have a trip for over a year and that those two instances are recorded in the results. Guest 2 never had a gap of over a year and therefor has no records in the results. Guest 3 has not had a trip in over a year but without have the return trip currently does not qualify for the result set. Should Guest 3 ever make another trip they would then be added to the result set.

---

Edit 2: Working Query

Thanks to @Code4ml I got this working. Here is the complete query.

```
Select
     Guest_ID, CurrentTrip, DaysBetween,  Lasttrip

From (

Select
     Guest_ID
    ,Lag(Trip_Date,1) Over(Partition by Guest_ID Order by Trip_Date) as LastTrip    
    ,Trip_Date as CurrentTrip
    ,DATEDIFF(d,Lag(Trip_Date,1) Over(Partition by Guest_ID Order by Trip_Date),Trip_Date) as DaysBetween

From UCS

) as A

Where DaysBetween > 365
```

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Comment: Makes sense I will work that up and add it in. Thanks for the advice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try SQL `LAG` [function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lag-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) to access previous trip date like below.

```
SELECT guest_id, trip_date,
LAG (trip_date,1) OVER (PARTITION BY guest_id ORDER BY trip_date desc) AS prev_trip_date
FROM tripsTable
```

Now you can use this as a subquery to calculate number of days between trips and filter the data as required.

Comment: Thank you for this info. I will give this a shot. I have not heard of the Lag function before so I will do some research and see if i can make it work.

Comment: This looks like it is going to get me what I need Thank you so much. I am able to get the trip and prev trip date and then just use a datediff on those even in the same select to get days between. Now I just need to add a subquery or temp table or something to filter down to just the records with over 365 days. Thank you so much.